# Only google andriod apps wont connect to internet on my school network

Tags: connection-issues, google, internet

First off, im not a student or teacher, i am an IT trainee at a very large school. We have 8 IT personal including myself.

I have asked around but non of the other guys seem to know why it happens my 98% of the time google apps dont work on out network on amdroid devices, id imagine the same goes for chromebooks but im yet to test that.

I cannot use apps such as google now, google play, google+, ect. Is it possible that they use some sort of vpn features because i know that vpns are blocked on our network due to my testing.

Also would anyone have a list of addresses and ports that i could add to our whitelist, if so please share that with me.

Any help would be appreciated reatly. Students are allowed to bring their own devices so it causes issues with the students who have android devices and need to download an app for their class or so,e other task using a google app.

Thatnk you in advance for any help you could offer.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Google DNS

DNS 1: 8.8.8.8
DNS 2: 8.8.4.4

you can add it to the WIFI AP/Router Config so its used by the DHCP

or you can manually Add it to the device wifi config:

Settings > Wifi > Long Press on Wifi Connection Name > Modify Network/Edit > IP Settings > Note the IP Address> Select Static > Type in the IP and Gateway then enter google dns and save

the setup on device route should be used to test if its the DNS if working setting it up on the Router is the better Soulution.